# Error logging into website that uses Oracle Access Manager when using headless browser

Tags: oracle, automation, phantomjs

I am attempting to write an automation script for a process on a website using PhantomJS. I have done this same type of automation many times before, but I am having trouble with this one particular website that uses Oracle Access Manager.

When I log in with Chrome or any other desktop browser, I have no problems. However, when I try to log in with the headless browser I receive an OAM9 error which is very unspecific "for security reasons"

I have tried changing the user agent string and ignoring bad ssl certificates, I am running out of ideas and my higher ups promised this functionality to someone. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I feel your pain, but S.O. is about solving evidenced based problems. You'll need to include a small sample of code that does work, and the smallest sample of code that demonstrates your problem as well as exact text of error msgs. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box on selected text to keep the formatting as code/data/errMsgs/etc. Good luck.

Comment: If you can't get it done with PhantomJS, use *Chrome or any other desktop browser* through [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)